Why is this direct object noun in the Genitive case?
I am confused as to why the noun 'ответа' is in the Genitive singular case after the verb
Text is  'я не знаю ответа' and 'я не знаю ответов'  - plural.

Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! Please don't use taglines, thanks and other chitchat in the posts. Thank you!
